# How would I go about saving snaps (UIImage) to the sandbox?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, snapchat

I'm creating a Theos tweak for my jailbroken iPhone and I'm stuck on a feature. So far I can block screenshot detection and replay detection, add infinite text, and have the app open directly to the feed. The feature I'm stuck on is saving incoming and outgoing snaps (and stories, but one step at a time). I used the FLEXible tweak from Cydia to assist me and I noticed that the snaps have something to do with "UIImage." From what I know I have to somehow convert this UIImage to *.jpg or *.png and save it somewhere (I'm looking to save it to the app's Documents directory).

I searched around the site and found the following that may be helpful:

```
// Convert UIImage to JPEG
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1); // 1 is compression quality

// Identify the home directory and file name    
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"]; 

// Write the file.  Choose YES atomically to enforce an all or none write. Use the NO flag if partially written files are okay which can occur in cases of corruption
[imgData writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

and

```
// Create paths to output images
NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];

// Write a UIImage to JPEG with minimum compression (best quality)
// The value 'image' must be a UIImage object
// The value '1.0' represents image compression quality as value from 0.0 to 1.0
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

// Write image to PNG
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

(like I said I **found** this; it is **not** my code).

Bah, I'm not sure how I would incorporate this. Any help?

Comment: The code you posted will indeed convert a UIImage (a Cocoa object that holds an image) into JPEG data, and the rest of the code will save the data to a file in the app's documents directory.

I know quite a bit about iOS but I don't do Jailbroken development, so I'm not sure what you mean by "incorporate this".  Incorporate it into what, exactly? (I wouldn't know a "Theos tweak" if it bit me on the butt.)

Comment: You don't need Theos to develop tweaks, it just makes things easier. So I imagine you wouldn't even have to know what it means to help (thanks for answering!). Essentially what I want to do is have a snap automatically save to the documents directory when I open it, and automatically save snaps I've sent after pressing the send button.

Comment: Ok... If you have a UIImage in `image` at the beginning of your code it should result in saving a JPEG to `Test.jpg` in the app's documents directory. However, if this is a "tweak" then I'm not sure there will be an app. It isn't clear to me what "sandbox document directory" means for a tweak.

Comment: By the app's sandbox directory I just meant the app's Documents directory, my bad. Which set of code makes more sense to use?

Comment: Also, forget I said anything about being jailbroken, just pretend I'm creating an app and am looking to do this.

Comment: well if this tweak work with all apps so u need to save snaps from each app i recommend creating a deamon and use **IPC** to send the snap and the deamon will manage all snaps

Comment: I'm not sure how to store UIImage so that I can save it. Any tips?